# moment.localeData is not a function error message

Tags: javascript

I'm using `moment` library, I want to initial `localeData` function.

but I got this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: moment.localeData is not a function
```

---

**my moment version is: `"^2.24.0"`.**

```
 var moment = require('moment')
 console.log('moment',moment.localeData())
```

Comment: var moment = require('moment.moment') i think will solve it.